# Get CPU usage in bash, without top or sysstat

Tags: bash, sed, cpu-usage

My test script looks like this:

```
prev_total_cpu=0
prev_idle_cpu=0

while true
do
 tempenv=$(grep "cpu " /proc/stat)
 #get cpu times
 read cpu user nice system idle <<< "$tempenv"

 #calculate total cpu time
 let total=$[$user + $nice + $system + $idle]

 #calculate delta total and delta idle
 prev_total="prev_total_$cpu"
 prev_idle="prev_idle_$cpu"
 let delta_total=$[$total-${!prev_total}]
 let delta_idle=$[$idle-${!prev_idle}]

 #calculate cpu usage
 printf "$cpu: $[100*($delta_total-$delta_idle)/$delta_total]%% "

 #remember total and idle times
 let prev_total_$cpu="$total"
 let prev_idle_$cpu="$idle"

 echo ""
 sleep 1
done
```

Now, the same thing with multiple CPU support:

```
prev_total_cpu=0
prev_idle_cpu=0
prev_total_cpu0=0
prev_idle_cpu0=0
prev_total_cpu1=0
prev_idle_cpu1=0

while true
do
 #loop through cpus
 grep "cpu" /proc/stat | while IFS='\n' read tempenv
 do
  #get cpu times
  read cpu user nice system idle <<< "$tempenv"

  #calculate total cpu time
  let total=$[$user + $nice + $system + $idle]

  #calculate delta total and delta idle
  prev_total="prev_total_$cpu"
  prev_idle="prev_idle_$cpu"
  let delta_total=$[$total-${!prev_total}]
  let delta_idle=$[$idle-${!prev_idle}]

  #calculate cpu usage
  printf "$cpu: $[100*($delta_total-$delta_idle)/$delta_total]%% "

  #remember total and idle times
  let prev_total_$cpu="$total"
  let prev_idle_$cpu="$idle"
 done
 echo ""
 sleep 1
done
```

Doesn't work - it shows the same numbers over and over again. What am I doing wrong?

Sub-question:

I would like to initialize `prev_total_$cpu`and `prev_idle_$cpu` in a loop, but I don't know how to set the condition. I need the opposite of `sed -ne 's/^cpu\(.*\) .*/\1/p' /proc/stat` so I can loop through its output and do the initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
grep "cpu" /proc/stat | while IFS='\n' read tempenv
do
    ...
done
```

Your while loop runs on a subshell environment.

One solution would be to use process substitution instead:

```
while IFS='\n' read tempenv
do
    ...
done < <(grep "cpu" /proc/stat)
```

Another way is to enable `lastpipe` option if Bash supports it:

```
shopt -s lastpipe
... loop goes next ...
```

Adding some suggestions to your code, when doing arithmetic operations in Bash you better use `(( ))` format e.g.:

```
(( total = user + nice + system + idle ))
```

It might also be better to use `-n` than `printf`:

```
echo -n "$cpu: $(( 100 * ($delta_total - $delta_idle) / $delta_total ))%% "
```

Lastly, I do hope you really mean that you run your script with `Bash` and not other shells like `Ksh`. They are very different. Bash is a shell but `Shell != Bash`.

Comment: For some reason, I never got `< <()` to work. I always get "syntax error near unexpected token '<'".

Comment: @Ulrik What's the output of `bash --version`?

Comment: I am using GNU bash, version 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin). It is a testing environment,as all the bash scripts in my project should run on any "real" Linux distribution.

Comment: And yes, I have seen
`let total=$[$user + $nice + $system + $idle]`

`"total=$user + $nice + $system + $idle"`

`((let total=$[$user + $nice + $system + $idle ))`

They all do the same, bu I don't know what is the fundamental difference (since they all spawn a sub-shell)

Comment: `(( ))` doesn't summon a subshell. And I think neither does any of your methods. But having `let` inside `(( ))` is wrong. Like I said the issue about having a subshell is all about how you pipe input to your loop. And `x | while` format summons a subshell.